# Mysql - Simple Add to cart database is being complicated.

Tags: php, mysql

I am stuck in a situation, I have three tables `customer` , `stock` , `trolley`. In customer I have fields `id (pk)` , `username`, `password`, `date of birth`.

In stock I have fields `stock number` , `quantity` , `id (pk)`. While in the trolley I have fields `cart_id (pk)` ,`customer_id (fk)` ,`paid`.

Now My scenario is I want to store the stock selected by customer , in the trolley . But I dont know how it will happen. Stock table's `id (pk)` is auto increment and so does trolley's `cart_id (pk)` is auto increment. How can I store the stock selected by user and the cart id in separate table. In the end its my requirement that after saving the data , I need to store customer_id, cart_id and paid in trolley table too.

Comment: Why not store the cart items in the session like most e-commerce platforms do? Also, is a "trolley" the same thing as a "cart"?

Comment: yes same thing.

Comment: Its a simple task asked by teacher, just html php and msyql, no ecomerce website.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with storing this data in the database. In fact it is quite common. That is how your cart can stay with your account regardless of the machine or session.

Comment: How can I store the stock selected by user and the cart id in separate table ?

Comment: The typical way to deal with this is to have two tables. CartHeader and CartItems. The header holds the account information and items tables holds details about each line item to be ordered.

Comment: Can you please post in detail the answer.

Comment: Two issues with that...first is you stated this is for a school project. If I do the work for you how do you anticipate learning anything? Secondly, I pretty much did give you the details.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144286/discussion-between-usman-dabay-khan-and-sean-lange).